# mathjax inline style change

Tags: css, mathjax

I am trying to change the style of a mathjax radical sign
and of an exponent. my code is

```
_stringOfHtml += "\\(^{"+tString+"}\\)"
```

and

```
_stringOfHtml += "\\(\\sqrt{"+tString+tString + "}\\)"
```

When I try to do this:

```
"\\(^{"+tString+ "}\\{style{font-family:reportschool, TeX, Arial, sans-serif;}\\)";
```

it does not work- I want to change it inline . Can anyone tell me how to add the style change?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems you're facing.

1. the syntax of `\style` is `\style{css}{math}`.
2. You cannot override math font settings this way as MathJax only supports particular fonts, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html for more information. (You could override the font settings for `\text{}` that way, e.g., `\style{font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}{\text{hello}}`
3. Even if you could override the font, your results would likely be bad. Neither Reportschool nor Arial have the necessary glyphs to build stretchy characters such as roots.

Answer (score 0):

\class{css-class-name}{math} is another way of applying custom style